# Picturebox location change 20 times per second not redrawing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, panel, picturebox, repaint

I'm trying to make a few images do the nice slidey thingy that I've seen lots of Microsoft applications use.  The one where the movement starts slow speeds up half way there and then comes to a nice slow stop in it's new location.  I've got all the calculations figured out, getting and setting the picture box locations, Confirmation using `console.writeline` that the image locations are correct, and even a test run that works in a simplified format.

But in the full blown version It's not repainting the image. In fact, it looks like nothing has happened at all while the script is running.  I've tried `Me.Refresh()`, `Invalidate()`, `Timer.Enabled = True/False`, and `Me.Update()`.  None of which have worked.  The last step is the most frustrating: I'm calling my `SetPanelLocation()` method at the end to ensure that the panel ends up in the final location regardless of if the movement worked.  Nothing happens on this call either, even though immediately after this routine fails I can call the same method from another user event and it starts working again like nothing was wrong.

I'm creating my own PictureBox class called `clsFeedImageBox` which inherits `PictureBox` that includes this functionality (along with other features).  Each image is only 300x225 pixels so they're not massive images that take a lot of time to redraw.  Each instance of this class is in a common `Forms.SplitterPanel`.  I use a lot of comments out of habit so i left them in here, maybe they'll add some light.

```
Public Class clsFeedImgBox
  Inherits PictureBox

  Private iRank As Integer 'rank in whatever feed this file gets put in
  Private iRankTarget As Integer 'rank to move to when rank feed event starts
  Private iTopStart As Integer 'starting top location before feed event
  Private iTopTarget As Integer 'final Top location after feed event
  Private WithEvents tMyTimer As New System.Timers.Timer
  Private WithEvents oParent As FeedBase 'splitter panel, all location info comes from the parent

  Public Sub New(ByRef sender As FeedBase, ByVal rank as Integer)
    'set objects
    oParent = sender
    'set .Image property to pre-made thumbnail
    Image.FromFile(ThumbPath) 'ThumbPath is a property which is set by this point (some code has been removed)
    'setup initial position
    setPanelLocation(rank)
    'set autosize
    Me.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    'set Image Scroll timer interval to 20 fps (1000 / 20 = 50)
    tMyTimer.Interval = 50
  End Sub

  Public Sub scroll(ByVal newRank As Integer)
    'setPanelLocation(newRank) <== this works, timed movements don't
    iRankTarget = newRank
    iTopStart = Me.Top
    iTopTarget = oParent.ImgTop(newRank) 'gets an integer for the new Top location
    tMyTimer.Start()
  End Sub

  Private Sub myScrollStep() Handles tMyTimer.Elapsed
    'tMyTimer.Enabled = False 'this idea with the enabled = True at the end didn't work
    iTickCount += 1
    Dim iScrollPerc As Integer 'scroll % between Start and End * 100
    iScrollPerc = oParent.ScrollStep(iTickCount, Rank) 'this part works
    Console.WriteLine(strThumbName & " scrollPerc: " & iScrollPerc.ToString)
    If iScrollPerc >= 100 Then
        'scroll event complete
        Console.WriteLine(strThumbName & " SetFinalLocation")
        Me.setPanelLocation(iRankTarget)  '<== This line doesn't work here, but works when called by other means
        'stop Feed updates
        tMyTimer.Stop()
        'reset iTickCount for next movement
        iTickCount = 0
    Else
        'scrolling still going
        Dim newTop As Integer
        newTop = Math.Round(iTopTarget - (((100 - iScrollPerc) * (iTopTarget - iTopStart)) / 100)) 'this part works
        'Console.WriteLine(strThumbName & " TopTarget: " & newTop)
        Me.Top = newTop 'Nothing happens here
    End If
    'Me.Left = oParent.ImgLeft
    'Me.Width = oParent.ImgWidth
    'Me.Height = oParent.ImgHeight 'that didn't work
    'Me.Refresh() 'this didn't work
    'Invalidate() 'this didn't do much good either
    'Me.Update() 'Aaaaand no cigar, time for StackOverflow
    'tMyTimer.Enabled = True
  End Sub

  Public Sub setPanelLocation(ByVal rank As Integer)
    iRank = rank
    Me.MyRePaint()
  End Sub

  Public Sub MyRePaint()
    'repaint image box with everything in it's current rank
    Me.Left = oParent.ImgLeft
    Me.Top = oParent.ImgTop(iRank)
    Me.Width = oParent.ImgWidth
    Me.Height = oParent.ImgHeight
  End Sub
End Class
```

What gives?  There must be some inner workings of VB.NET that will help me figure this out.  I'm using VS 2012 and Win8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms754130.aspx) application and use a [Slider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.aspx) control instead of "manually" making a slider with planes, picture boxes, etc, etc.